# AWS DMS erro SQL_ERROR SqlState: 28000

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am trying to create a source in DMS with SQL Server and I am getting this error. Can anybody help me?

```
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect  Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: 28000 NativeError: 18456 Message: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'app'.
```

Comment: Check that DMS can connect to both databases as a first step. Make sure for any AWS resources security groups allow inbound access for DMS, and on premise is reachable. If this is ok, validate credentials for both DBS. Try logging in using what you have :)

Comment: @mokugo-devops  thanks, but that didn’t solve it,
I made an ec2 instance using the same parameters and via telnet with this access.